# Default documents in search results

Tags: search, sharepoint-foundation, hyperlink

In my Foundation 2010 If I search something i get the result as links to DispForm ie:

http://myserver/Lists/Orders/DispForm.aspx?ID=6937

but actually my default document to display it is **DispFormAlt.aspx**.

How can i force to put correct links keeping in mind that some lists have still DispForm.aspx as their default document?

Comment: Was the DispFormAlt.aspx set as the Display form in the list settings?

Comment: Yes, DispFormAlt.aspx is my default display document, I've checked in both Sharepoint designer and in list tools when I click on edit default display form.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add following to your scope and see if this works?

Add a rule
user property and pick contentclass = STS_ListItem_850
and choose exclude.

save the scope, go the search service application page, and about in the middle you can click on "run now" so you dont have to wait 15 minutes to propagate changes to your scope. (i may take couple of minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate the XSLT of the SearchCoreResults webpart in your search center.
This way, you are able to change the search results output. Make use of a XSL Choose or If element to determine the list name/guid. It's quite dirty - but I think it will work.